# How to I set up Grafana behind an IIS Reverse Proxy?

Tags: iis, grafana, reverse-proxy

I am using Grafana installed on Windows / IIS.  I would like to host it behind a reverse proxy subdomain name along side other web services, and to use Azure AD (aka Entra ID) authentication.  That is `https://grafana.example.com`.

I have configured the AzureAd login in `custom.ini` correctly.  I am able to go to `http://localhost:3000` and can successfully use the "Microsoft Login" button to use AzureAD to log in.  Woot.

I am now following instructions provided by Grafana at https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#configure-iis and https://grafana.com/tutorials/iis/, but they primarily deal with hosting as a subpath, not as a "root" site.

I have installed the IIS Rewrite module. For IIS, I created a new "empty" website then added an inbound rule per the instructions - match `(.*)` and rewrite as `http://localhost:3000/{R:1}`.  This also works - I can go to `https://grafana.example.com` and it loads the login page.  Sweet!

However, when I use the "Microsoft Login" button from my FQDN, it just redirects me back to the login page.

Using the network inspector, I see different redirect behaviors when using the Microsoft Login depending on if I'm accessing it via localhost or grafana.example.com:

- localhost returns a 302 with Location header of  `https://loign.microsoft.com/{tenantId}/oauthv2/v2.0/blahblahblah` - this is expected.
- grafana.example.com returns a 302 with Location header of `https://grafana.example.com/{tenantId}/blahblahblah`

What am I missing that the AzureAD integration ignores the `auth_url` setting of my OAuth provider?

Note: I also enabled Google OAuth with junk values for the secrets, etc. and got the same behavior.  This feels like a bug or misconfiguration for my server or all OAuth providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround is to use and outbound rewrite rule to match the specific "incorrect" redirect.  It feels hacky though - the Grafana module should be generating the correct URL.

```
<outboundRules>
  <rule name="HeaderRewrite" preCondition="IsRedirect" enabled="true">
    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="https://grafana.example.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="https://login.microsoft.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="IsRedirect">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3\d\d" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

For clarity, this is rewriting the redirect URL from `grafana.example.com/.....` to instead be the correct `login.microsoft.com/.....` URL, using a precondition where the HTTP response code is `3xx`.  Per HTTP specs, [anything in the 300-399 range is considered a redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#redirection_messages).

Comment: I'm not really comfortable with it being a "solution".  It is at best a workaround, and underlies either a lack of understanding of the many Grafana configuration options, or a defect in their system.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be considered an workaround. It's also great that it will lead more people in the right direction.